# How to render server response directly in react router v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is my React Router v5 code. I render special react components for certain routes (/demo, /home and /shop). However, for the rest of the routes, I just want to display the `<div>Some content from server</div>` elements returned by the server without any treatment. "Some content from server" is different for each path. In some cases it could be an image inside a div and in some other cases it could text inside a div. I want to display whatever I receive from the server between the Header and Footer elements.

```
const Root = () => {

  return(
    <div className="site">
      <ProvideAuthContext>
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/demo/"} component={Demo}/>
            <Route exact path={"/home/"} component={Home}/>
            <ProtectedRoute path={"/shop/"}>
              <Shop />
            </ProtectedRoute>
            <Route path={"*"} render={() =>
              <div>
                XXXX
              </div>
              }
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </ProvideAuthContext>
    </div>
  )

}
```

How do I write the last Route path for * ?

Comment: Please [edit] to include all relevant details and code ([mcve]) you are trying to work with. What data is being fetched on these *extraneous* pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <Route path="/" render={() =>
          <div>
            I want to display the div element received from the server here.
          </div>
          }
        />
```

...**path="/"**...

Comment: I have updated the question. If the user visits any route other than the three special routes, I just want to display the server response between the Header and the Footer. The server content changes based on the route I visit.

Comment: in path="/" show ServerContent component which makes request to server and renders it....